# Could we open somehow app store or safari from Push Notification without launching our app?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I almost sure we can't, but i can't find docs witch will say it directly - "No we can't"
I know push can open our app and we can handle info from push ductionary.
But i need to be sure we cant open App Store or Safari (by link) from push without launching our app.
Sorry for dummy question. Thx in advance.

Comment: Just an FYI based an assumption from your question. I am assuming you're trying to advertise another app through Push Notification. I would strongly advise against this. Not only is it bad taste, it's also against the App Store Review Guidelines. See Section 5 (in particular 5.5 + 5.6) https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cant. A push message from your app will open your app or do nothing. Right after your app is open you can open any other app of course.